# Python Create new variable inside For Loop

Tags: python

I've read through some existing answers and maybe I'm just not firing on all cylinders today because I'm completely lost...

I have a for loop currently that fixes a few things in some Pandas dataframes. I've truncated it to show what I'm doing here:

```
prime1 = pd.read_excel('10_27_2017 to 10_30_2017 Prime Run.xlsx')
prime2 = pd.read_excel('10_28_2018 to 10_30_2018 Plugging Event.xlsx')
prime3 = pd.read_excel('2_15_2019 to 2_16_2019 Prime Run.xlsx')
prime4 = pd.read_excel('3_23_2019 to 3_24_2019 Prime Run.xlsx')
prime5 = pd.read_excel('4_11_2017 to 4_15_2017 Plugging Event.xlsx')
prime6 = pd.read_excel('6_1_2019 to 6_4_2019 Prime Run.xlsx')
prime7 = pd.read_excel('6_20_2018 to 6_22_2018 Prime Run.xlsx')
prime8 = pd.read_excel('7_10_2017 to 7_14_2017 Plugging Event.xlsx')
prime9 = pd.read_excel('8_27_2018 to 8_29_2018 Plugging Event.xlsx')

dlist = [prime1,prime2,prime3,prime4,prime5,prime6,prime7,prime8,prime9]
for entry in dlist:
    print(entry.shape)
    entry.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Date'}, inplace=True )
    next
```

This works for what I need to do in terms of updated column names and a few other minor things. Next however I need to melt each of the variables

```
prime1_melt = pd.melt(prime1, id_vars = ['Date'], var_name='Feature', value_name='Value')
```

works perfectly fine if I do them one at a time. But I'd like to just include it in my loop to happen auto-magically. I just seem to be lost as to how to implement the second list of variable names that end in "_melt"

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need a collection of objects, use an actual collection like a list, tuple, or dict. Don't use variable names to emulate existing data types.

Comment: @jordanm can you give me a hint as to how to make that work?  do I define a list with each variable set on a row and then loop over row numbers?...

Comment: `foo = {}; foo['prime1'] = pd.melt(prime1, ....)`

Comment: @jordanm each of the primes is a dataframe imported from a CSV. Should I start out importing them differently than I have? I've updated the initial question to include the brute force import method I used

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jordanm I was able to solve this. I adjusted to get everything done in a single go with the following code:

```
imps = {'10_27_2017 to 10_30_2017 Prime Run.xlsx','2_15_2019 to 2_16_2019 Prime Run.xlsx','3_23_2019 to 3_24_2019 Prime Run.xlsx',
        '6_1_2019 to 6_4_2019 Prime Run.xlsx','6_20_2018 to 6_22_2018 Prime Run.xlsx',}
prime = {}
prime_melt = {}
ctr = 0
for lfile in imps:
    prime[ctr] = pd.read_excel(lfile)
    prime[ctr].rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Date'}, inplace=True )
    prime_melt[ctr] = pd.melt(prime[ctr], id_vars = ['Date'], var_name='Date', value_name='Value')

    print(lfile)
    print("  ",prime[ctr].shape)
    print("  ",prime_melt[ctr].shape)

    ctr+=1
    next
```